# How to nest promises in JS and have them resolved in different times?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, settimeout, es6-promise

I thought that by running the code below the numbers 1, 2 and 4 would show up on the screen within 1 second after the other. But they show up at the same time.

As my nested resolve is inside a `setTimeout()`, shouldn’t they be resolved only one second after the previous one?

```
var test = document.getElementById("test");

new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(() => resolve(1), 1000);
}).then(result => {
  test.innerHTML += result + "<br>";
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(result * 2, 2000));
  });
}).then(result => {
  test.innerHTML += result + "<br>";
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(result * 2, 3000));
  });
}).then(result => {
  test.innerHTML += result;
});
```

Comment: it's a typo, you didnt pass the second argument to other 2 setTimeouts, instead you passed two arguments to resolve callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass the second argument correctly for the setTimeout

```js
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(() => resolve(1), 1000);
}).then(result => {
  console.log(result)
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(result * 2),2000);
  });
}).then(result => {
 console.log(result)
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(result * 2),3000);
  });
}).then(result => {
  console.log(result)
});
```